# Can't install firmware updates through software center

Tags: updates, software-center

Software Center is showing me I have two firmware updates ready to be installed:

[image]

But each time I click "update", it disappears as if it's loading the install and then instantly reappears. Am I doing something wrong?

EDIT:

Here's the output of `sudo apt update`:

```
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [111 kB]     
Hit:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Ign:4 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/4.4 InRelease      
Hit:5 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/4.4 Release        
Hit:6 https://typora.io/linux ./ InRelease                                     
Get:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [98.3 kB]  
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [107 kB]      
Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/qbittorrent-team/qbittorrent-stable/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:10 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages [359 kB]
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main i386 Packages [212 kB]
Get:13 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [208 kB]
Get:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/hertg/egpu-switcher/ubuntu focal InRelease [18.0 kB]
Get:15 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 Packages [166 kB]
Get:16 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [186 kB]
Get:17 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2,464 B]
Get:18 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [24.2 kB]
E: Repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/hertg/egpu-switcher/ubuntu focal InRelease' changed its 'Label' value from 'egpu-switcher' to 'EGPU Switcher'
N: This must be accepted explicitly before updates for this repository can be applied. See apt-secure(8) manpage for details.
Do you want to accept these changes and continue updating from this repository? [y/N] y
Get:19 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [52.2 kB]          
Get:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/hertg/egpu-switcher/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages [456 B]              
Fetched 1,545 kB in 17s (88.8 kB/s)                                                                       
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
6 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

And of `sudo apt upgrade`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libfprint-2-tod1 libllvm9 libllvm9:i386
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages have been kept back:
  mongodb-org mongodb-org-mongos mongodb-org-server mongodb-org-shell mongodb-org-tools
The following packages will be upgraded:
  egpu-switcher
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
Need to get 9,668 B of archives.
After this operation, 3,072 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/hertg/egpu-switcher/ubuntu focal/main amd64 egpu-switcher amd64 0.15.0 [9,668 B]
Fetched 9,668 B in 0s (29.7 kB/s)         
(Reading database ... 259111 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../egpu-switcher_0.15.0_amd64.deb ...
[info] Starting cleanup process
[info] Removing the 'egpu.service' systemd service
Removed /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/egpu.service.
[success] Done... Finished cleanup
Unpacking egpu-switcher (0.15.0) over (0.14.0) ...
Setting up egpu-switcher (0.15.0) ...
[info] Using existing configuration file at '/etc/egpu-switcher/egpu-switcher.conf''.
[info] If you want to reconfigure egpu-switcher, please run 'egpu-switcher config'.
[info] Automatically detecting if egpu is connected... 
[info] EGPU is disconnected.
[info] Create symlink /etc/X11/xorg.conf -> /etc/X11/xorg.conf.internal
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/graphical.target.wants/egpu.service → /etc/systemd/system/egpu.service.
[success] Done... Setup finished
```

Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...

Comment: please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1275946/edit) your question and include the output of `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`

Comment: @Nmath no problem, edited

Comment: OK, you do have multiple issues with your package management, and some questionable choices in the use of [PPA](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out-for).  Ex: `mongodb` and `qbittorrent` are both available in the `universe` repo, so you really shouldn't have a PPA for these unless you absolutely need a feature that's not in the release available in the default channel. There are also errors with the PPA hosting `egpu-switcher`, but it looks like you fixed them with these commands.

Comment: You also have broken packages, and need to run `sudo apt autoremove` to get rid of them. And you have held back pacakges of `mongodb` probably because of PPA.  You should clear up these issues to allow updates and before trying to install new software

Comment: I don't know why it's using PPA or what I even did to make that happen

Comment: When you originally installed the software, you must have added a PPA instead of getting it from the software center or `apt`. You can remove the PPA, but you should back up any files or databases used by the software, and your configs might need to be readjusted. When you run `sudo apt update` you want it to end with `All packages are up to date` without any errors.  I don't see the firmware packages in the current output though.  Can you get any more info about these packages from the software center?  Package names would be helpful.